# C++ Comma Delimited Txt File

Tags: c++

I am working with my simple system that using .txt file as database in C++. In my case, my code is working but the output is has too many repeats.. My system shows the list of name is the text file (second row in commas).

This is the sample of my txt file:

```
2015-1111,Christian Karl,M
2015-1112,Joshua Evans,M
2015-1115,Jean Chloe,F
2015-1113,Shairene Traxe,F
2015-1114,Paul Howard,M
```

And my desire output:

```
Christian Karl
Joshua Evans
Jean Chloe
Shairene Traxe
Paul Howard
```

Here is the problem.. It has many repeats..
My current output:

```
Christian Karl
Christian Karl
Christian Karl
Joshua Evans
Joshua Evans
Joshua Evans
Jean Chloe
Jean Chloe
Jean Chloe
Shairene Traxe
Shairene Traxe
Shairene Traxe
Paul Howard
Paul Howard
Paul Howard
```

I try to debug many times my code but seems nothing happen..

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void split(const string& s, char c,
           vector<string>& v) {
   string::size_type i = 0;
   string::size_type j = s.find(c);
   while (j != string::npos) {
      v.push_back(s.substr(i, j-i));
      i = ++j;
      j = s.find(c, j);
      if (j == string::npos)
         v.push_back(s.substr(i, s.length( )));
   }
}
int main( ) {
  ifstream in("db.txt");

  char str[255];
  while(in) {
    in.getline(str, 255);  // delim defaults to '\n'

   vector<string> v;
   split(str, ',', v);
   for (int i = 0; i < v.size( ); ++i) {
      cout << v[1] << '\n';
   }

  }

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Anyone who can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Remove this

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size( ); ++i) {
  cout << v[1] << '\n';
```

}

and use this instead

```
if(v.size()>0){
    cout << v[1] << '\n';
}
else{
    break;
}
```

or better this

```
cout << v[1] << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks got it! But says an error "Expression: vector subscript out of range."

Comment: That is because you are not checking the end of file before printing the line